# Export Excel Using Yii

Tags: php, excel, yii

I am new to Yii. I am doing a scenario to export to Excel option. I am half way through. The values are getting populated in the necessary field. But if Empty value is present the cell In Excel gets the next column value, so there is a mismatch happening, so how to perform a blank cell in Excel Export.

```
    if(!empty($cmApprRes)){
                        foreach($cmApprRes as $log){
                            $arrData[$i][]=CHtml::encode($log->cm_log_description);
                        }
                    }

                    else
//if there is no data in the log table the corresponding column should be shown as blank.
//but that is not working please suggest an option for else
                    {

                    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is Fixed. sorry  it was a simple step.

```
if(!empty($cmApprRes)){
                        foreach($cmApprRes as $log){
                            $arrData[$i][]=CHtml::encode($log->cm_log_description);
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
$arrData[$i][]="";
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to solve your Excel - exporting needs by writing a solution yourself then I'd suggest to avoid reinventing the wheel (unless completely necessary or, for some reason, desired) and use a third party library instead. You could use ***yiiBasicXls*** (https://github.com/faustow/yiiBasicXls). 
It's very simple to use:

**Installation**

Download XlsExporter.php and move it into /protected/components/ in your own Yii application.

**Usage**

Once the XlsExporter component is in place, you just need to:

- Seach for whatever data you want to create the Xls file about
- Call the downloadXls function with the correct parameters:

  - `filename`: String that will be used as name for the output filename. No need to append '.xls' since it will be added by default. *(required)*
  - `data`: Active record data set (required)
  - `title`: String that will be
    used as the title displayed on top of the exported lines. Defaults to
    false.
  - `header`: Boolean to show/hide header. Defaults to false.
  - `fields`: Array of fields to export. Defaults to false.
  - `type`: String that explains what's being exported for the end user (use plural) like 'users', 'cars', etc. Defaults to 'lines'.

**Example**

For example (on some controller):

```
public function actionDownloadReport() {
    $fields = array('email', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'type');

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->select = $fields;
    $criteria->condition = "firstName = 'John'";
    $criteria->order = 'lastName';
    $users = users::model()->findAll($criteria);

    XlsExporter::downloadXls('report', $users, 'List of users called John', true, $fields, 'users');
}
```

Once that's in place, calling `yoursite.com/somecontroller/downloadReport` will trigger the download of the xls file in the browser.